# Python Beautifulsoup return values twice

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm writing code to pull some values but the code returns the values twice.

My code:

```
def getResponse(url, user_agent):
    page = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent': user_agent.random})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def getListing(soup):
    list_result = soup.find("div", {"class": ["pageMainContent"]})
    list_results = list_result.find_all("div", {"class": ["fontPreviewTitle"]})
    for one_result in list_results:
        product_url = one_result.find("a").get("href")
        yield product_url



url = "https://www.1001freefonts.com/3d-fonts.php"

soup = getResponse(url, UserAgent())

for url in getListing(soup):
    print(url)
```

Output :

```
Saraths-MacBook-Air:~ evilslab$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /Users/evilslab/Documents/Websites/www.futurepoint.dev.cc/dobuyme/SCRAPE/fonts.py
/orange-juice.font
/orange-juice.font
/from-cartoon-blocks.font
/from-cartoon-blocks.font
/cantate-beveled.font
/cantate-beveled.font
/wedgie.font
/wedgie.font
/alba.font
/alba.font
```

How i can fix this issue ?, How to avoid duplicate values

Comment: ```for url in set(getListing(soup)):``` <--- use set Just a hack.

Comment: Why it return twice ?

Comment: because that page is having those tags twice. for example `<a href="/agent-orange.font">Agent Orange</a>` is mentioned twice in page source

Comment: there are two divs `<div class="fontPreviewTitle responsiveMobileCenter">`
and `<div class="fontPreviewTitle">` which are having those tags

Answer (score -1):

in your getListing() function, replace list_results with the below

```
list_results = list_result.find_all("div", {"class": ["fontPreviewTitle responsiveMobileCenter"]})
```

You will get unique output with the above. And no more changes are required in your code